# Julia custom module scope of variables

Tags: module, scope, julia

I am starting writing my first custom module in Julia.
What I am doing is writing all the files in a folder, then import them in a `ModuleName.jl` file and eventually writing a test program which executes a precompiled `main()` function which calls my custom module (I like keeping a modular style of programming).

The problem is that I think I am missing something on the use of `using` and `import` keywords. In my test file I have the following lines:

```
push!(LOAD_PATH,"./ModuleNameFolder")
using ModuleName
```

I thought that functions of `ModuleName` if loaded with `using` could be called without explicit `ModuleName.myfunct()`, but only through `myfunct()` while this is not the case. If I omit the `ModuleName` the compiler throws an `UndefVarError`.
What am I doing wrong? I would like to bring all the functions of my custom module on the main scope

Comment: (from ignorance) why are you using `push! + using` instead of just `include("./ModuleNameFolder/ModuleName")`?

Comment: @Ehub please move one step back and make it a question about using Julia modules. In your question you are already half-way to some wrong approach but I am not sure what is that you exactly need. Most likely you are asking how to use modules? Have also a look at https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/ and whatever is unclear ask here!

Comment: @DecowVR because I thought it was a naive way to import a module. Maybe what I have done is an overkill, thank you for your remark

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel I want to avoid writing `ModuleName.myfunct()` every time I call `myfunct()`. I thought that `using` keyword would have made `myfunct()` available directly, but it does not seem the case

Comment: in that case in module definition you need to have `export myfunc`. In this way each time you do `using MyModule` the `myfunc` will be brought to the `Main` namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Julia.
What do you mean by `precompiled main() function`? Tests in Julia are normally set on a specific file that is run automatically at each push of your code on the repository that you use to host the code.

Any how, try `include ./ModuleName` followed by `using .ModuleName` (note the dot). **And remember to `export` the objects in `ModuleName` that you want to make available directly.**

Have a look on my tutorial: https://syl1.gitbook.io/julia-language-a-concise-tutorial/language-core/11-developing-julia-packages

Comment: I mean that I have written a `main()` function with tests for each function of the module. Thank you very much for your tutorial

Comment: It turned out that I missed `export` on functions of my module. Thank you again for your advice!

Comment: @Ehub: you don't need to wrap the tests in a "main" function, just write the test functions